# User defined entities in OWL ontologies?

Tags: rdf, owl

I am seeing an OWL ontology with user defined tags like:

```xml
<relatedEvent>
   <participants> ... </participatants>
   <location> ... </location>
   <time> ... </time>
   <process> ... </process>
</relatedEvent>
```

Is there any documentation on how and when to use custom entity or property?

More content of the OWL file:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <rdf:RDF
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        xmlns:protege="http://protege.stanford.edu/plugins/owl/protege#"
        xmlns:xsp="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/2005/08/07/xsp.owl#"
        xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
        xmlns="http://www.sim.whu.edu.cn/historyevent.owl#"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
        xmlns:historytime="http://www.sim.whu.edu.cn/historytime.owl#"
        xmlns:swrl="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#"
        xmlns:swrlb="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrlb#"
        xmlns:historyfigure="http://www.sim.whu.edu.cn/historyfigure.owl#"
        xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
      xml:base="http://www.sim.whu.edu.cn/historyevent.owl">
      <owl:Ontology rdf:about="">
        <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.sim.whu.edu.cn/historyfigure.owl"/>
      </owl:Ontology>
      <rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://www.sim.whu.edu.cn/historylocation.owl#HistoricalLocation"/>
      <rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://www.sim.whu.edu.cn/historytime.owl#HistoricalTime"/>
      <owl:Class rdf:ID="SanGuoEvent">
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
          <owl:Class rdf:ID="HistoricalEvent"/>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
        ></rdfs:label>
      </owl:Class>
    ...

   <SanGuoEvent rdf:ID="濡須口之戰_sanguozhi">
    <influence rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >  魏軍南征皆失敗，之後曹丕親自帶兵南進。  </influence>
    <process rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >  黃武元年。 </process>

  </SanGuoEvent>

 ...
    </rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: That is not an OWL ontology but an XML document. There are various OWL serialization formats, like RDF/XML, OWL Function Syntax, Manchester OWL Syntax, etc. All the documentation is indeed in the OWL 2 W3C recommendation which is online.

Comment: @AKSW, I added more content to the OWL file, and it looks exactly like an OWL ontology. Right?

Comment: The owl fragment does not show any custom tags. Can you show the custom tags in the context of the ontology?

Comment: @user697911 but where are the "custom tags" now that you added a proper OWL ontology document (or at least a fragment of it)

Comment: @AKSW, as you can see I just updated, the <SanGuoEvent > and <influence>, <process > are custom tags.

Comment: @Ignazio, please see my update.

Comment: Ok, but to be honest, I don't why you're asking it. Do you want to write RDF/XML syntax by hand? Why? Otherwise, don't think in terms of tags when using OWL but axioms.

Comment: That context is insufficient. Either that's part of an XML literal, in which case the XML will not be interpreted but simply made available to the parser for further processing by application specific code, or that's not a valid RDF file.

Comment: @AKSW, I download this ontology from a web to study, so I was trying to understand it.

Comment: @Ignazio. It's a valid RDF file. I can load in Protege as an ontology. I guess the tag <SanguoEvent> is defined and imported from another OWL file. Several OWL ontology are imported, if you look at the header of the code I posted.

Comment: Well, the short answer is. There are multiple ways to generate the RDF/XML serialization of an RDF graph. Documentation is [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/)